# Get zoomed-in area coordinates

Tags: android, imageview

I got an `ImageView` that has some gesture recognizers:pan, zoom and so on. An user is zooming on a certain area of the image. When he presses a button, i want to insert a view(a circle for example) to the parent `ImageView`.

I wonder how can i get an area's center coordinates or get a rect representing the zoomed image after you zoom in on a certain area of the `ImageView`. I can get very easily the `MotionEvent` event but i can't figure it out how to detect the new coordinates of the  zoomed-in area.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That, what you are looking for is called "Crop". There are many libraries to crop images. Choose one of them, or check how they resolving your issue. [There](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) you can find some Cropping libraries.

Comment: I really don't want to crop the image. If i want to add another view on the parent ImageView, i need to have some sorts of coordinates. I just want to get some coordinates from the zoomed area of the ImageView. I'm zooming on a ImageView and I want to get the center of that zoomed area.

Comment: As i said there: "or check how they resolving your issue." check source code of any 3rd party crop lib and check how they get coordinates of zoomed / cropped area.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). There is an attribute `setOnMatrixChangeListener` which will return the changed coordinates.
If you are already making use of any other library, there must be some attribute available for the same.If you tell the library, can check for the attribute

Comment: This is the library that I'm using. In onMatrixChanged() i save the new changed rectangle but it isn't working Naaz.

Comment: Check if you have only one instance of Photoviewattacher. If that's the case you will never get changed coordinates.

Comment: I have only one instance. I tried to get the display rect: mAttacher.getDisplayRect() and have some processing on that rect

Comment: I've tried this response that presumably returns that rectangle, and I tried to insert a view in the center of it, but the calculated center it's not always corect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566737/im-having-trouble-understand-what-photoviews-getdisplayrect-actually-returns

Comment: yes. That's the problem. A new instance should be created everytime, then only will you get the changed coordinates.

Comment: Declare " PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;"

Comment: Refer to the following code.                                                 mAttacher=new PhotoViewAttacher(image);
mAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener() {
    SwipeListner swipeListner= (SwipeListner) getActivity();

    @Override
    public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {

        if (mAttacher.getScale() > 1) {

            swipeListner.setSwipeEnabled(false,currentPage);
        } else {

            swipeListner.setSwipeEnabled(true,currentPage);
        }


    }
});

Comment: SwipeListener is custom interface which is implemented in activity.                                                                                                           @Override
public void setSwipeEnabled(boolean swipe,int pageNo) {

    if(pageNo==mPager.getCurrentItem()) {
        if (swipe)
            mPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
        else
            mPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
    }else{


    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HackyViewPager code 
public class HackyViewPager extends ViewPager {

```
private Context cont;
```

private boolean enabled;

```
public HackyViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    isLocked = false;
    cont=context;

}

public HackyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    cont=context;

    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

}